# How do I modify the URL to a taxonomy term?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have a vocabulary called Industry with four terms. I have edited the terms to keep the URL to be automatically generated. They are following this convention:

```
industry/term1, industry/term2, etc...
```

I want the convention to be (without the "industry/"):

```
term1, term2, etc...
```

I configured the URL alias patterns like so for Taxonomy Term paths:

**Default pattern:**
[term:vocabulary]/[term:name]

**Pattern for all *Industry* paths:**
[term:name]

However, when I navigate to the URL (i.e. /term1), I get this message:

```
The requested page "/term1" could not be found.
```

On top of that, I have a view for a block that generates this vocabulary as a list with the links so users can click on them and go to the taxonomy page. I have the option selected for each term:name that we need to "Link this field to its taxonomy term page". When that block is rendered, it generates a URL like so:

```
[term:vocabulary]/[term:name]
```

This is not what I expected. I expected the URL to be `[term:name]`.
I am new to Drupal and still learning things about it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you have a URL Alias in the system for "/term1".

It might be mostly the case of all your old Alias existing in the system not the new once. If you don't find the update URL alias under admin/config/search/path. Then it just a simple bulk regenerate (admin/config/search/path/update_bulk).

Please ensure you have selected

- Taxonomy term
- Update the URL alias for paths having an old URL alias (at Times you may want to use the option Regenerate URL aliases for all paths)

[image]

Comment: I just tried that and got the message "no new URLs to generate."

Comment: Try with generate url alias for all paths, try to delete alias for all taxonomy terms from the delete tab

Comment: Okay, thank you so much, @berramou! I had to delete all the aliases. And then I had to regenerate them!

Comment: Welcome I'm glad that helped